# @Html.Actionlink not hyperlinking to actual controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

In a mvc project there are two controller

1. `HomeController`
   Contain a view `client`
2. `EndorsementController`
   Contain a View `add`

from the `add` view in `EndorsmentController` I wrote an actionlink as below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "client", "Home", new { @style = "color: #FFF" })
```

but when ever I click this actionlink it is looking for a URL

```
Endorsement/client
```

Actually it should be

```
Home/Client
```

Why it is not taking the correct controller name? Anything I am missing?

Comment: You using the wrong overload - `@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "client", "Home", null, new { @style = "color: #FFF" })` (although what you would actually be generating is `Endorsement/client?length=4`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for correcting..

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong `ActionLink` overload method. You can try the following code in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "client", "Home", null, new { @style = "color: #FFF" })
```

The rendered HTML will look something like this:

```
<a href="/Home/client" style="color: #FFF">Back to Home</a>
```

Just a pointer try to capitalise your view names, instead of using `client` try `Client`. Both will work.

Answer (score 1):

you put your html attribute in "`object route values`"
you have to put `null` into it

use the following syntax to get correct output:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "client", "Home", null, new { @style = "color: #FFF" })
```

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA96y.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The point to take home is the particular overload you want to use. Since this is the you want to use synthax : `//linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes` the below is how your `ActionLink` should look like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "Client", "Home", null, new { @style = "color: #FFF" })
```

What you were using before follows this synthax: `// linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes` which is shown below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "client", "Home", new { @style = "color: #FFF" })
```

Hence the `Url` confusion

Comment: OP's code was not `linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues` - it was `linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes`